# How to select nested numeric functions in MySQL in one line

Tags: mysql, select

For example I want to select the difference of MAX and MIN like this:

```
select sum(max(population) - min(population)) from city;
```

I know I can do it by doing two selects but is there any way to do it in one line?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind looks like it works like this

```
select (max(population)) - (min(population)) from city;
```